# Ring homomorphism from Wiki

Tags: abstract-algebra

From the page of Wiki:

$f: \mathbb Z_6\rightarrow Z_6$ defined by $f([a_6])=[4a_6]$ is a ring homomorphism.

$f(a)=\{a_n\}=a \pmod n$.

The kernel is $3\cdot \mathbb Z_6$ and image is $2\cdot\mathbb Z_6$.

I don't know if I understood well:

is $3\cdot \mathbb Z_6=\{0,3,6,9,12,15\}$?

Is $\mathbb Z_6=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$?

Can somebody explain why kernel and image are $3\cdot \mathbb Z_6$ and $2\cdot\mathbb Z_6$?

reduced mod 6 is $3\cdot \mathbb Z_6=\{0,3\}$?

Comment: For your own good you may want to check with your professor if he's using the definition "ring"="ring with 1" or "ring"="ring without 1", because the former requires that homomorphisms send $1$ to $1$, whereas according to the latter this map would indeed qualify as a homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of the map are all the elements $a \in \mathbb Z_6$ such that $f(a) = 6 k$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$ (because these elements are zero mod $6$). We get $4a = 6k$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$ for $a=0, a=3$, so the kernel is
$$3 \cdot \mathbb Z_6 = \{0,3\}$$
because $3 \cdot \mathbb Z_6 = \{0,3,6,9,12,15\} = \{0,3\}$ reduced mod $6$.

In a similar fashion we get
$$\text{Im}(f) = \{0,4,8,12,16,20\} = \{0,2,4\} = 2 \cdot \mathbb Z_6$$